# Driving Parallel Mosfets

Tags: parallel, mosfet-driver, powermosfet

I have a total of 20 IRF3205 mosfets in a H bridge configuration for switching a transfromer to get pure sine wave output. (Five mosfets at each end of thr H bridge).

- Datasheet says total gate charge of 150nC max for each mosfet. Switching frequency is 26khz max. Gate voltage is limited to 12V max because regulated 12V supply is fed to driving IC.
- Driving IC is HIP4082 with peak current of 1.25A.
- Gate resistors for each mosfet is around 110 ohm. Single pulldown resistor for each 5 mosfets(100k). 18V Zener diodes for protection.
- Max load current is 200A. They are all mounted on seperate beefy heatsinks and I will be using heatsinks as drain terminals.

## Questions

- Will I be cooking those fets in transition state or will they just do okay?
- Is there a better value of gate resistors and pulldown resistors for each mosfets?

Edit:

## Question

*Should I even care about drive problems? Frequency is just 20-30khz.

Comment: When you say "switching a transformer to get a pure sine wave output" that raises some red flags for me. Alternatively, in another interpretation of your post, it sounds like you want to run the MOSFETs as a linear devices which is oxymoronic because you also say H-bridge. If you gave us a schematic and more info, then I would not need to do all this guessing.

Comment: @DKNguyen He's probably synthesizing a "pure sinewave" using pwm.

Comment: @Drew Yes, spwm.

Comment: I just want to know if they will blow up at 200A (100A average for each group of 5 fets) because of insufficiant gate drive and consequently overheating. Thats why I am asking for correct gate resistor value for each fet.

Comment: Mosfets are for turning on and off, if the voltage is in between, then the mosfet will dissipate significant current as heat. If they are paralleled this might be acceptable, simulating in a SPICE package is probably the easiest thing to do to find out the thermal numbers

Comment: 110ohms it too high to switch one 150nC MOSFET at 26kHz at 1.25A, let alone five. The resistor need only be just high to dampen oscillations.

Comment: `Single pulldown resistor for each 5 mosfets(100k)` - The [HIP4082](https://datasheet.octopart.com/HIP4082IPZ-Renesas-datasheet-62343061.pdf) does not mention any base resistors, nor pull-downs.

Comment: I would build a prototype and test it. Start with a low load current and work your way up. As HIP mentioned you will probably see improvements by reducing that gate drive resistor to the absolute minimum. You can also try different gate drivers or reduce the switching frequency.

Comment: @DKNguyen Total 10 Fets are to be drived in each cycle(5 lower ones and 5 opposite upper ones). Each fet has gate resistor of 110 ohm total. So 10 resistors of 110ohm in parallel means 11 ohm of total resistance for the driver IC. Max voltage for driving is 11-12V. That gives more than 1A possible current from driver. Am I right?

Comment: @rdtsc Thats why I am asking.

Comment: @Drew What is absolute minimum resistance in this case? I have no idea.

Comment: @VoltageSpike Thanks but I am no good with simulation.

Comment: @vikas the other way is with a hand calculation, and that's hard

Comment: @VikasKumar  It will probably be specified somewhere in the gate driver datasheet. The purpose is peak current limiting; and damping of ringing as DKNguyen said.

Comment: `Total 10 Fets are to be driven in each cycle(5 lower ones and 5 opposite upper ones)` - So wait, are you saying that one HIP4082 is driving multiple MOSFETs in parallel? Each gate capacitance acts like a dead short at t=0 and on each transition, so 10x one gate capacitance will behave like 1 MOSFET with 10x the gate capacitance, likely slowing the edges significantly. Use more HIP4082's and ensure they have adequate bypass capacitance so that all gates transition as quickly as possible.

Comment: @rdtsc What about using two IR2110 to driver them all, HIP4082 output goes into both IR2110s. Is it a good choice?